# "Cannot find or open the PDB file" of a class library found in another solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

### **Issue:**

*SolutionA*(MVC Solution) cannot load the PDB file of one of the class libraries in *SolutionB*(Business Logic Class Libraries). (It loads the other class library pdbs just fine)

### **Environment:**

- .Net 4.0
- MVC
- C#
- Visual Studio 2012
- PDB file found in class library's Debug/bin folder
- PDB file found in all projects(Debug/bin) that reference this class library.
- PDB Creation time is the same as Compile time

**Local Paths:**

```
• C:\MyPath\WK_SOLUTIONA\Dev_BF\SolutionA
• C:\MyPath\WK_SOLUTIONB\Prod\SolutionB
```

Where there are references of SolutionA to SolutionB (ie dll reference) a reference path was set (Properties > Reference Paths)

**Symbol Load Information:**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\launcher_devbf\0a01d364\380351a5\assembly\dl3\9ae300b0\47b07c94_5317cf01\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
b:\23\575\src\SolutionBClassLibrary \obj\Release\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\R9962~1.SCH\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb\4c48672e09774c67b9f8001ecafacbd71\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Users\R9962~1.SCH\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb\4c48672e09774c67b9f8001ecafacbd71\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\MyPath\WK_SOLUTIONB\Prod\SolutionB\bin\Debug\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb: PDB does not match image.
SYMSRV:  C:\Users\R9962~1.SCH\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb\4C48672E09774C67B9F8001ECAFACBD71\SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb not found
 
 
SYMSRV:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb/4C48672E09774C67B9F8001ECAFACBD71/SolutionBClassLibrary.pdb not found
 
 
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
```

### **What I have tried:**

- Made sure both solutions where cleaned and rebuilt
- Cleared symbols cache and manually deleted the contents of the following: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Manually inserted the pdb file in the symbols cache  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET File
- Point symbols path "Load Symbols" to the debug folder of the SolutionBClassLibrary. Result: "A matching symbol file was not found in this folder"
- Tools > Options > Debugging > set "Enable .NET Framework source stepping"  (for both solutions)
- Deleted the IIS virtual directory and recreated it.
- Debug from the *SoltionA* into *SolutionB*
- Started debugging from *SolutionA* and continued debugging on *SolutionB*. Whenever this specific class library is hit it ignores my changes.

Comment: `PDB does not match image`

Comment: Are you sure there is actually a pdb file for the library?

Comment: @jamesthollowell it is show in the Debug/bin folders where it is referenced and also in it's own Debug/bin folder

Comment: @SLaks will look into that. Any suggestions as to why there is that issue?

Comment: Are you debugging a service using "Attach to process" ? If so, the location of the executable you are attaching to may be different from the location of the PDBs.

Comment: Updated my question. I wasn't using "Attatch to process" though i tried it from SolutionB and it ignored my changes

Comment: Can you attach a sample project to reproduce it?

Comment: Both solutions are of monolithic proportions. I doubt i can reproduce in a sample project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround to achieve the desired result. Basically manually overwritten the dlls that where referenced with the ones that had my changes. Since this is a local environment there are no repercussions.

This is however as I said, a `workaround` and goes outside the point of using reference paths in the first place.

Edit: Apparently now all my changes are being tracked since I've done this. So this was indeed the correct answer!